# Loop through list of lists and divide list values

Tags: python, pandas, list

I would like to iterate through two lists of lists and divide them by eachother.

Starting with:

```
patient1_list_A = [1,2,3]
patient2_list_A = [4,5,6]
patient3_list_A = [7,8,9]
patient1_list_B = [10,11,12]
patient2_list_B = [13,14,15]
patient3_list_B = [16,17,18]

list_A=[patient1_list_A, patient2_list_A, patient3_list_A]
list_B=[patient1_list_B, patient2_list_B, patient3_list_B]
```

I'd like the output to be a new list filled with the normalized patient values.

```
normalized_list=[normalized_patient1, normalized_patient2, normalized_patient3]
```

where,

```
normalized_patient1=[1/10, 2/11, 3/12]
normalized_patient2=[4/13,5/14,6/15]
normalized_patient3=[7/16, 8/17, 9/18]
```

I am thinking of something like this, but I am unsure how to make this also loop through the list_A and list_B of patients.

```
normalized_patient1_list=[]
for i,j in zip(patient1_list_A,patient1_list_B):
    normalized_patient1_list.append(i/j)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use `zip` to concatenate the sublist and there element and use metric operations

```
patient1_list_A = [1,2,3]
patient2_list_A = [4,5,6]
patient3_list_A = [7,8,9]
patient1_list_B = [10,11,12]
patient2_list_B = [13,14,15]
patient3_list_B = [16,17,18]

list_A=[patient1_list_A, patient2_list_A, patient3_list_A]
list_B=[patient1_list_B, patient2_list_B, patient3_list_B]

# just for str method for your calu
result = [["{}/{}".format(c, d) for c, d in zip(a, b)] for a,b in zip(list_A, list_B) ]
# output [['1/10', '2/11', '3/12'], ['4/13', '5/14', '6/15'], ['7/16', '8/17', '9/18']]
# actual calculated result
normalized_patient1_list = [[c/d for c, d in zip(a, b)] for a,b in zip(list_A, list_B) ]
"""output
  [[0.1, 0.18181818181818182, 0.25],
  [0.3076923076923077, 0.35714285714285715, 0.4],
  [0.4375, 0.47058823529411764, 0.5]]

"""
```

Comment: if there is a 0 in patientX_list_B, is there a way to make an exception and not use those c, d values in the operation?

Comment: @Emerson you can add the if statement there like `[c/d for c, d in zip(a, b) if d!=0 else None]` or instead of list comprehension you can use normal loop for better control

Answer (score 0):

Here's solution to your problem. Try this.

```
import itertools

patient1_list_A = [1,2,3]
patient2_list_A = [4,5,6]
patient3_list_A = [7,8,9]
patient1_list_B = [10,11,12]
patient2_list_B = [13,14,15]
patient3_list_B = [16,17,18]
list_A=[patient1_list_A, patient2_list_A, patient3_list_A]
list_B=[patient1_list_B, patient2_list_B, patient3_list_B]
normalized_A = list(itertools.chain(*list_A))
normalized_B = list(itertools.chain(*list_B))
new=[]
for i in range(len(normalized_A)):
    new.append(round((normalized_A[i])/(normalized_B[i]),3))
new
```

Comment: Output would be like this: **[0.1, 0.182, 0.25, 0.308, 0.357, 0.4, 0.438, 0.471, 0.5]**